# How can I prove whether a $9\times 9$ square can be filled with L-shaped pieces in a completely "regular" way?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, recreational-mathematics

There are a great many ways to fill a $9\times 9$ square with L-shaped pieces. One of them is below.

[image: 9x9 square filled with L-shaped pieces]

Now, note that there are eleven $2\times 3$ rectangles that are formed, as well as a larger L shape. There is one "irregular" piece, which has been colored in green. What I think of as being "regular" is a bit subjective (as in aesthetically appealing), but I think it suffices to define a regular piece as being part of a rectangle or larger L-shape.

**I conjecture that there must be at least one irregular piece.** How can I prove this? (Alternatively, if I'm wrong, what would be a counterexample?)

The proof I'm thinking of is that all rectangles that can fit in a $9\times 9$ and can be constructed from L-pieces must have at least one side with even length, and that larger L-shapes also have dimensions that are of even lengths. Hence, as $9 \cdot 9 = 81$ is odd and all "regular" formations have even numbers of squares in them, there must be at least one square that does not fit into a "regular" formation, which them requires at least one "irregular" L-piece, which completes the proof. Is this rigorous enough (after adding mini-proofs that show why regular shapes must have even numbers of squares in them), or am I lacking important details?

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me.

Comment: 1) You need to define clearly what regular shapes are. Are $2 \times 3$ rectangles and the larger $L$ shapes formed by four smaller pieces the only allowed regular shapes?
2) You need to show the regular shapes are disjoint from each other. Otherwise, you parity based argument fail.
Other than these two points, your argument sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually if you consider a "larger L shape" as regular, you can take your green L
as part of such a larger L shape:

[image]

Comment: Aaand there's the counterexample! Right under my nose!

Comment: @coffeemath: Mmm...it's an L-shape that's three times as large. I count 9 L-pieces, thus 27 squares, which can and does form an L-shape where each "square" is composed of 9 smaller squares.

Comment: Yes I see it now, the being "part of" a larger L in this case has that larger L including all but the red or light blue parts of the board.

Answer (score 2):

The $9 \times 9$ square takes $27$ L pieces to cover it.  If the only regular pieces are $2 \times 3$ rectangles (which take two pieces) and your larger L (which takes four pieces), there must be at least one odd L piece because both the regular shapes take an even number of pieces.

Comment: +1 for a simpler way to state my thought process and thus simplify the (false) proof.